# Can't find error library on Mac OS X

Tags: c, error-handling, static, static-libraries

I wanted to use the error() function that's defined in the error.h library file and I cannot find that on my Mac. I use 10.10.4 OSX Yosemite. I think can work arounf errno and strerror but just wanted to find out if there's an alternative.

Comment: Errno is in `errno.h` and strerror is in `string.h` according to Wikipedia

Comment: I can locate those under standard library /usr/include. it's error.h i want.

Comment: The `error()` function is a GNU extension.  It is available only if you are using the GNU C library.  Per its own man page, it should not be used in any program intended to be portable.

Answer (score 7):

you should instead use `#include <mach/error.h>` on Mac OS